Salesforce SOQL query, get Accounts that have more than 3 Contacts
I want to get Accounts, not just Id but Name and maybe some other field values, and write following query.
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Account 
WHERE Id IN 
  ( SELECT AccountId, Count(Id)
    FROM Contact
    GROUP BY AccountId
    HAVING Count(Id) > 3
  )

It gives 'Unknown error parsing query' error.

It's not very pretty but one way would be
SELECT COUNT(Id), MAX(Account.Id), MAX(Account.Name), MAX(Account.BillingCity)
FROM Contact
GROUP BY AccountId
HAVING COUNT(Id) >= 3
LIMIT 2000

It has to be limited to 2K because GROUP BY doesn't support querying next chunk of data ("cursor" if you're familiar with the concept from "normal" databases). You can use OFFSET to get another 2K out of it.
If that's not enough you'd need to make a number field (custom? reuse existing NumberOfEmployees?), have some automation that populates it (homemade rollup summary) and filter by that...
